# controlling SSL at page level in IIS

Tags: ssl, iis-6

For various reason I would like to turn off SSL at a page level. Is this best practice? What should I look out for while I am doing this? What is considered the safest way to do this? The way I was going to do this was:

Right click on the page-> navigate to properties-> click file security->then uncheck require secure channel.

Will this effect other pages. Any help would be great thank you

Comment: I can't think of a good reason to do this. As far as security goes, I'm sure this isn't best practice.

Comment: Agreed.  I wouldn't recommend it.  Is there a specific reason you'd like to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That setting you are on about wouldn't work anyway. Note how it says REQUIRE.
If it was ticked What this would mean is that if someone tried to connect on http it would fail or redirect them to https. Unticking it simply means they can connect on both. So if the previous page they were on was https and a link takes them to this page it will stay on https.

I think you will need to code it into the pages themselves. As in the hyper link itself you will need to specify the full URL starting with http:// rather than a relative URL. There are other methods as well like redirectors